# Can I get any compensation for 2-week turnaround on 2015 MacBook Pro battery recall?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

I have a 2015 MacBook Pro (still under AppleCare) that is covered under the battery recall issue. However, the machine is my primary work computer, and the Apple Store has said that they have to ship it out to have it repaired, since they do not have the tools in-store to safely replace the battery.

Being without this computer for two weeks will significantly hinder my ability to do my work. Is there any way to receive compensation from Apple due to this?

Comment: No, there's no way of getting compensation for this.  People have been trying to do this with Apple products for years.  Unless you join a class-action lawsuit, you're on your own.  If you have a business account with Apple, you might be able to obtain a loaner from them.

Comment: Apple Stores do have a 14-day return policy. You could "buy" a new laptop and return it 13 days later. I've even heard some folks say that Apple employees have encouraged them to do this. Use at your own risk, of course.

Comment: I've read/heard of a few people doing what @TJLuoma suggested so you wouldn't be the only one.

Comment: @TJLuoma this actually would make a good answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

Not likely. Apple can't ship these devices by air due to safety reasons, and there are a lot of them.

If everyone who was inconvenienced by this got together and collectively sued Apple, and won, you might get enough to pay for a fast food meal. In 2024.

Comment: Do you know of any examples of suits around similar topics with Apple?

Answer (score 0):

Apple has offers for business users including loaner devices.
If your device is business critical you should look into it, your local retail store will be happy to help you.

Link for you:
https://www.apple.com/retail/business/jointventure/terms.html

Comment: Unless Joint Venture Services was joined at the time of purchase this is of no use.